# Why does the managed object returned by Restkit only have the attributes (of CoreData) and not also the values (other properties)?

Tags: macos, mapping, restkit, nsmanagedobject

The problem is that in my mapping I have some properties which are persistent while others are not. So, in callback the object only has the attributes (of CoreData) but not the values (other properties).

In other words, although I have checked that the "items" property is mapped correctly with a breakpoint in Restkit library this properties are nil finally in the main thread.

NSManagedObject subclass:

```
@interface Item : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSNumber * serverID;
// Not persisted in CoreData
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *followers;

@end



@implementation Item

@dynamic serverID;
.....
@synthesize followers;

@end
```

NSObject subclass:

```
@interface User : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;


@end

@implementation User

@synthesize name;

@end
```

And the mapping is:

```
// Method in Item class
+ (RKEntityMapping *)itemMapping {
    static RKEntityMapping *mapping = nil;
    if (!mapping) {
        mapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass(self.class)
                                  inManagedObjectStore:[RKObjectManager sharedManager].managedObjectStore];
        [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name": @"name"}];
        [mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"followers" toKeyPath:@"followers" withMapping:[User mapping]]];

        mapping.identificationAttributes = @[@"serverID"];

    }
    return mapping.copy;
}

// Method in User class
+ (RKObjectMapping *)userMapping {
    RKObjectMapping *mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:self.class];
    [mapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{@"name": @"name"}];
    return mapping;
}
```

Comment: What does your RestKit mapping setup look like? What is items an array of?

Comment: @EricHedstrom thanks for your answers. I have added more information and example code